# toshiba, windows 8.1, skype

Tags: windows-8.1, toshiba-laptop

I want to be able to mix my voice from the microphone and an audio file while making a Skype call. So that the person I'm phoning can either hear my voice or the recording if this is playing.
Toshiba does not allow to install stereo mix. 
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: How to achieve what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Stereo Mix…
It is usually missing in most Toshiba computers.
Here is how to get it back.

- Download the latest Conexant SmartAudio driver for your laptop downloadable at http://support.toshiba.com/.
- Create a new folder for the driver and extract the zipped driver files to it with WinRAR.
- You should find a couple of folders. Browse through them until you find the folder labeled W7-64/ W7-32, depending on whether you are using a 32-bit or 64-bit OS.

There will be an .inf file inside. There should only be one file with that extension. Open it in Notepad.

- Now search in notepad until you find this section:

> ;HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\PcBeepCtrlEnable,Enable,1,01
>   ;HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\PcBeepCtrlEnable,EPname,1,01
>   ;HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\PcBeepCtrlEnable,DefGainSettings,1,00,07,00,07
>   ;HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\PcBeepCtrlEnable,MuteGainSettings,1,00,00
>   ;HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\PcBeepCtrlEnable,Flags,1,00
>   ;HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\StereoMixEnable,Enable,1,01
>   ;HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\StereoMixEnable,MixAssocSeq,1,E0,E0
>   ;HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\StereoMixEnable,MuteGainSettings,1,00,00

Note the semi-colons in front of each line. Remove all the semi-colons so the 8 lines above read like this:

> HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\PcBeepCtrlEnable,Enable,1,01
>   HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\PcBeepCtrlEnable,EPname,1,01
>   HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\PcBeepCtrlEnable,DefGainSettings,1,00,07,00,07
>   HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\PcBeepCtrlEnable,MuteGainSettings,1,00,00
>   HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\PcBeepCtrlEnable,Flags,1,00
>   HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\StereoMixEnable,Enable,1,01
>   HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\StereoMixEnable,MixAssocSeq,1,E0,E0
>   HKR,%EPattributePath%\EpSettings\StereoMixEnable,MuteGainSettings,1,00,00

Now cick "File" and "Save".

- Then go to Control Panel, Sounds and Hardware, Device Manager, Sound, Video, and Game Controllers, and right click on Conexant Smart Audio HD, select Update Driver Software.
- Go to Browse My Computer for Software, Let Me Pick From A List, Have Disk, and navigate to the .inf file (the one you edited in Notepad) in the folder on your desktop.
- It should tell you it is no longer digitally signed and might harm your computer. Install it anyways.
- Now open up your Sound tray. If you go to the "Recording" tab, and make sure "Show Disabled Devices" and "Show Disconnected Devices" are both checkmarked.
- Now you should have Stereo Mix. Right click on it and select "Enable".

Source : http://forums.computers.toshiba-europe.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=65162